# Catch enough IV to be in the FMS attack

Tags: wifi, wep

I am doing WEP attack test using FMS method (Fluhrer, Mantin and Shamir), but not capturing enough 4,000,000 to 6,000,000 IV.
Please show me how to catch enough IV.

Comment: There needs to be enough traffic to capture ...

Answer (score 1):

A classical way to catch enough packet (hence enough IVs) is to artificially generate traffic using ARP: it is a link layer protocol, so ARP packets are not
restricted by any kind of filters or rate limiting rules.

Most importantly, it is possible to re-inject a captured ARP request in order to generate a response, and repeat the operation until you have enough packets.
In practice, it is only a matter of time to gather enough packets, and it can be done quickly with a de-authenticate message send to a client. There are plenty of software (e.g. airplay) which does it very well.